# Effects on personal credit report of a dispute with a merchant

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I am curious:

I placed a credit card order with a merchant late last year for a subscription service as a Christmas gift.  It was an "X of the month" style subscription for a family member, of six months length.  To date, the merchant has made exactly two shipments, promises the moon, but refuses to follow through on my complaints.

I am strongly considering disputing this through the credit card as that is the only way I believe I will ever get satisfaction at this point.  The original purchase was in the range of a few hundred dollars, so an equitable refund would be about 2/3 that amount. All parties (merchant, credit company, myself) are in the United States.

My question is this:  What effect, if any, might this have on my own credit score?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disputing credit card charges should not have an effect on your credit score.

According to [Experian](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/disputing-charges-on-credit-card-account/):

> Disputing a charge on your credit card will not negatively affect your
>   credit standing, although the credit card company may add a statement
>   to your credit report indicating that the account is currently in
>   dispute.
>
> Although a dispute notation by itself would not be considered
>   negative, potential lenders may inquire as to the nature of the
>   dispute, and some may require that the dispute be resolved before
>   proceeding with an application for major purchases such as a mortgage.
>
> It is important to talk with your credit card company and be certain
>   you understand the process for disputing charges on your account, as
>   well as its policy for how the dispute will be reflected on your
>   credit reports, if at all.
>
> In some cases, you may be expected to continue to make payments on the
>   amount in dispute while the charges are being investigated. If so,
>   failure to make those payments while the investigation is pending
>   would likely result in your account being reported as delinquent,
>   which would then negatively affect your credit history and credit
>   scores. Late payments remain on your credit report for seven years
>   from the original delinquency date.

I have disputed charges on my credit card before, and I have never had an issue with it affecting my credit score/report. As long as you have proof that your disputes are legitimate (whether that be documents, receipts, etc.), then you should be fine.